# Интересная олимпиадная задача.

Tags: java, логика

Есть задачка, довольно простая, я думаю. Решение пришло сразу же: Мы ищем максимальный из дней (d-итых), и выводим какой это день недели. Т.к чтобы они могли встретится, все дни должны быть делителем наибольшего дня. (Те. мы заводим массив дней, и сортируем по убыванию, все элементы являются делителем первого) Валится на тесте 4. Не могу найти ошибку.

> Грин-де-Вальд хочет собрать своих сторонников. Но, к сожалению, он
>   может сделать это не в любой день. Всего у Грин-де-Вальда есть n
>   сторонников. Пронумеруем их от 1 до n. Сторонник с номером i, исходя
>   из личных убеждений, посещает место встречи каждые di дней (то есть
>   если интервал между двумя посещениями сторонника с номером i
>   составляет di дней). Грин-де-Вальд помнит, что в последний раз все его
>   сторонники одновременно появлялись на месте встречи в день недели с
>   номером s. Помогите ему определить, какой номер будет иметь день
>   недели, когда все сторонники снова одновременно окажутся на месте
>   встречи. Напомним, что в неделе 7 дней, Грин-де-Вальд пронумеровал их
>   числами от 1 до 7 в порядке

следования.
**Формат входных данных**
Первая строка входных данных содержит два целых числа n и s (1 ⩽ n ⩽ 105
, 1 ⩽ s ⩽ 7). Вторая
строка содержит n целых чисел di (1 ⩽ di ⩽ 20).
Формат выходных данных
**Выведите** единственное число от 1 до 7 — номер дня недели

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

/**
 * Created by Andrey on 31.12.2018.
 */
public class Main {
    static int scanInt() throws IOException {
        return parseInt(scanString());
    }



    static String scanString() throws IOException {
        while (tok == null || !tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
            tok = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
        }
        return tok.nextToken();
    }

    static BufferedReader in;
    static StringTokenizer tok;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = scanInt();
        int s = scanInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> days = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            days.add(scanInt());
        }
        days.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());



        ArrayList<Integer> week = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
            week.add(1);
            week.add(2);
            week.add(3);
            week.add(4);
            week.add(5);
            week.add(6);
            week.add(7);
        }

        System.out.println(week.get(s+days.get(0) - 1));







    }
}
```

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на контест. У меня есть идея, хотелось бы её проверить.

Comment: Ну или тестов дайте каких-нибудь.

Comment: @Егор Левоненко, это задачка с сайта codeforces.ru. Раздел тренировки, четвертая командная олимпиада, преступления Гриндевальда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал немного по-другому. Я бы нашёл НОК от всех `Di`, таким образом, найдя периодичность встреч.

Далее, я бы прибавил данное значение к дню нашей последней встречи, чтобы найти следующий день встречи, и взял бы его по модулю `7`.

Если ответ равен нулю, то выводим семь, т.к. `7/14/21/... % 7 == 0` и это стоит учесть.

Таким образом, решение схематически может выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
n, s = input()
d[]  = input_array()
period = lcm(d[0], d[1], ..., d[n - 1])
new_day = (s + period) % 7
if new_day == 0: new_day = 7
output(new_day)
```

Comment: Проверил решение на сайте, вроде работает.

Answer (score -1):

если так?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // число сторонников и день недели
    String[] nsStr = reader.readLine().split(" ");
    int n= Integer.parseInt(nsStr[0]); // число сторонников
    int s = Integer.parseInt(nsStr[1]); // день недели

    // период в днях для каждого сторонника
    String[] diStrArr = reader.readLine().split(" ");
    int[] di = new int[diStrArr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < diStrArr.length; i++) {
        di[i] = Integer.parseInt(diStrArr[i]);
    }

    // наименьшее общее кратное для всех периодов
    int gcd = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < di.length; i++) {
        gcd = gcd * di[i] / getLCM(gcd, di[i]);
    }

    // день недели
    int weekDay = (gcd + s) % 7;
    weekDay = weekDay == 0 ? 7 : weekDay;

    // вывод
    System.out.println(weekDay);
}

// наибольший общий делитель
public static int getLCM(int a, int b) {
    while (a != b) {
        int a1 = Math.min(a, b);
        int b1 = Math.abs(a - b);
        a = a1;
        b = b1;
    }
    return a;
}
```